# How do I add the page's slug to a link in a wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, url, widget, slug

I've been searching for over an hour so I'm really hoping someone can help me please.

I have a widget which includes a link e.g

```
<a href="/form/fill-in-form">Fill in our form</a>
```

But I'd like to add in the page slug to the link (so I can see it on the form). E.g if users are on my page mysite.com/listing/redcar I'd like them to see:
e.g

```
<a href="/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=SLUG">Fill in our form</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=redcar">Fill in our form</a>
```

But no matter what I do, I just can't get the slug to go into the URL in the Widget

I've tried

```
<a href="/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Fill in our form</a>
```

And dozens of other things but I just can't get anything to work.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

use global to get post slug

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
?>
<a href="/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=<?php echo $post_slug; ?>">Fill in our form</a>
```

you can also get slug by post id, do this

```
<?php
$post_id = POST_ID; //replace it with post id
$post_data = get_post($post_id); 
$post_slug = $post_data->post_name;
?> 
<a href="/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=<?php echo $post_slug; ?>">Fill in our form</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Regolith - I tried that but then the link just added %3C?php%20echo%20$post_slug;%20?%3E e.g it became:  https://www.mysite.com.au/form/fill-in-form/?myparameter=%3C?php%20echo%20$post_slug;%20?%3E

Comment: I'm using it in a widget

Comment: All good! I was putting the php into my functions but it goes in the widget itself :) Thanks so much Regolith